# All file in redo log group corrupt

Tags: oracle, transaction-log, recovery

```
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 2 of thread 1
ORA-00312: online log 2 thread 1: '/u02/oraredo/O12C/redo02b.rdo'
0RA-00312: online log 2 thread 1: '/u02/oraredo/O12C/redo02A.rdo'
```

i got this error in my trace file/alert log  this happen because all redo log file in my redo log group 2(status=current) is corrupted.

can i just do the following task to fix the problem

1.alter system switch logfile

2.alter system checkpoint

3.alter database clear logfile group 2

4.backup the database if the logfile not archived

or do i have to do a point in time recover until the latest good scn? if so why do i have to do a PITR instead of just clearing the log group?

Answer (score 0):

Please do follow this DOC ID as your scenario looks similar.

If your redo log file status=current or active may not be cleared - that time a PTR is needed to the last available archive log.

Redo Log Corruption - Dropping Redo Log Is Not Possible - CLEAR LOGFILE (Doc ID 1078456.6)